# Changing the name of a property from a model class

Tags: c#, reflection, console-application

I am wanting to change the name of the property that is currently in the model class for certain conditions. I was reading up on how to do this and ran into a possible solution for what I am wanting to do. However, when I do the following with Reflection it says

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

But in the model class I do have the name. Am I not using this correctly?

`Model class`:

```
public class Example1
 {

    public Property1 Property1 {get;set;}
 
 }

public class Property1
{
  public string Fruit {get; set;}
 
}
```

then I have the following

```
var firstName = "Car";

Example1 myProperties = new();

SetPropertyValue(myProperties, myProperties.Property1.Fruit, firstName);
```

....

```
 public static void SetPropertyValue(object p_object, string p_propertyName, object value)
 {
            PropertyInfo property = p_object.GetType().GetProperty(p_propertyName); // grabs the property name 
            property.SetValue(p_object, Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType), null);
 }
```

I do not seem to understand why it is giving me that message if I do have the property name there. Ultimately I am wanting to change the name of the property from Fruit to Car. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `myProperties.Property1.Fruit` you're passing the value of the property and not the name of the property. nameof(myProperties.Property1.Fruit) should do it

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! I went ahead and did it, but when it hits the last line in the `SetPropertyValue` .... `property.SetValue()` it says the same message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".... then says `property` was null. Is it because I am doing a `new()`? @Manuel

Comment: That's because `p_object` is of type `Example1` and doesn't have the property `Fruit`. You need to pass the object `myProperties.Property1` as the first argument of `SetPropertyValue`: `SetPropertyValue(myProperties.Property1, nameof(myProperties.Property1.Fruit), firstName);`. You also need to instatiate the property `Property1`: `Example1 myProperties = new(); myProperties.Property1 = new()`

Comment: I added an answer with the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the object `myProperties.Property1` as the first argument of the method `SetPropertyValue`:

```cs
SetPropertyValue(myProperties.Property1, nameof(myProperties.Property1.Fruit), firstName);
```

You also need to instatiate the property `Property1`:

```cs
Example1 myProperties = new();   
myProperties.Property1 = new();
```

Here's fixed for you

```cs
var firstName = "Car";
Example1 obj = new();
obj.Property1 = new();
SetPropertyValue(obj.Property1, nameof(Example1.Property1.Fruit), firstName);
```

Comment: Thank you! So with this, it would change the property name from Fruit to Car correct? Because when I debugged it, it is showing that the `Fruit` holds a value of `"Car"`. When I hover over the first parameter `obj.Property1` it shows `"Car"`, but I was thinking that it would completely change the property name from `Fruit` to `Car` and not add the value `Car` to the property `Fruit`?

Comment: The code above will set the value of the property "Fruit" of the object "Property 1" to "Car".

Comment: With "change the property name", do you mean adding the property "Car" to the object "Property1" and do something like "myProperties.Property1.Car = ..."?

Comment: Well replacing the name of "Property1" property to "Car" property...

Comment: If that is not possible, how would go about adding it (the property "Car") like you mentioned?

Comment: A good way of doing it is through a Dictionary<string, object>. You can do `dictionary.Add("Car", value)` and `dictionary.Remove("Property1")`.

Answer (score 2):

you should initiate inside property too

```
Example1 myProperties = new Example1 { Property1=new Property1 { } };
```